# Story board localization does not work after updating Xcode

Tags: swift

I did the localization in Arabic. It was working fine and now it when i changed da app to Arabic the storyboard labels and buttons are not changing to Arabic.

I couldn't find a solution. And recently i updated the Xcode version 11.5 earlier it was 11.3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in one of my projects. There s an **reload** feature in Xcode itself where you can convert the localization file to an **Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Storyboard** or a **Localizable String** file type. See [this](https://medium.com/@mario.negro.martin/easy-xib-and-storyboard-localization-b2794c69c9db) post. There is an explanation.

1. Go to your storyboard file from the **Project Navigation**
2. Open the inspector section
3. Find the section **Localization** under **File Inspector**
   [image]
4. Your file should be localized as a **Localizable String** (see picture above). Change it to the other file type or do the reverse.
5. After Xcode converted your file you should see the results. You can change your file back if you want.

Or alternatively you can - as a workaround - downgrade Xcode to an older version again until Apple fixes that.

Hope it helps!